# Как подключить библиотеку sfml к gcc на mac os?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, sfml

На линукс библиотека устанавливается одной командой

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

Как сделать это на mac os?

Comment: скачиваете с сайта архив https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/ под свою ось, потом прописываете пути в инклудами и библиотекам, ругаетесь, снова пишете на форумы, потом устанавливаете убунуту и дальше уже знаете, что делать

Answer (score 0):

На сайте sfml есть подробная инструкция - https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php - с картинками даже. Попробуйте её. А если не получится, ну тогда уже будем решать по мере возникновения проблем.

Comment: опять приехали минусаторы?